# How to block javascript based popups/new tabs in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, adblock

I use  ublock origin addon on chrome.  However, I have problems with sites which are ad lovers. when i enter those , they auto open new tab which is directed to ad site, or even worse new window of chrome which is small sized window and keeps teleporting between top left and bottom right. I can only stop this if i deactivate javascript on those sites. Which is bad because it also blocks some functionality.
so what can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! One quick precision, the addon is ublock or ublock origin?

Comment: thanks,sorry for not saying that. it is ublock origin,edited now

Comment: Have you tried blocking pop-ups via Settings > Cookies and Site permissions > Pop-ups and redirects ?

Comment: yes i did , it doesnt help :(